# how to restrict jquery trigger function to complete its task

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using `jQuery` to `trigger` the `keypress` event programatically. It works fine but the problem is that the code after `trigger event` is executed before trigger event gets completed. I have searched for some kind of `trigger.complete` function but perhaps there is no such function. So please tell how can I restrict the trigger function/event to complete before the next code is executed?

**Code:**

```
<script>
    $("#html-element").trigger ( {
        //task inside trigger
    } );

    alert('this should pop-up after the task inside trigger is finished.');
</script>
```

Comment: Just put return; inside curly braces before your code.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('#html-element').trigger(eventName, function() {
    //your trigger event task
    alert('this should pop-up after the task inside trigger is finished.');
});
```

Comment: here is what I am trying to do but it still does not works:  `document.getElementById("txtUrdu").focus();
      $('#txtUrdu').trigger('keypress', function() {
       document.getElementById("txtArabic").focus();
       $('#txtArabic').trigger('keypress');
      });`

Comment: same way you can add function in this trigger also $('#txtArabic').trigger('keypress' ,function(){"Your final trigger steps" ;  alert("put alert statement here")  });